# Fundamental Theorem of Statistics

Tags: probability

**English**

If I have 100 balls, and 40 are red and 60 are blue, what is the probability that selecting 10 balls at random will give me a 4/6 red:blue ratio within an error margin less than 20%?

**Mathish**

If I have a set containing N binary-state exemplars (ie, n are "x" and N-n are "not x"), and I choose a random subset of size M, what is the probability P that the proportion of "x" : "not x" exemplars chosen for the sample will match the actual proportion "x" : "not x" of exemplars in the set, to within a given error margin E?

**Some discussion**

I'm trying to find something that would work for unknown actual or samples ratios, so it should generalize over all possible X:notX sets.  This leaves only the following independent variables for the formula:

P = F(N, M, E)

Given the error margin, we can generalize a few more terms already, saying something like:

- Ssample = sample proportion
- Sactual = actual proportion

P = Probability(|Ssample(N, M) - Sactual(N)| < E)

What is P?

Comment: It is convenient to view it as sampling with replacement. If the sample size is modest compared to population size, the assumption does not change probabilities very much.

Comment: What is the "fundamental theorem of statistics"?

Answer (score 0):

Let us generalize your problem. Let there be $R$ red balls and $B$ blue balls. You take $T$ random samples and assume you get $X_R$ red balls. You need to find the following:

$P[\mid \frac {X_R}{T}-p \mid \geq \epsilon] $ where $p$ is the fraction of red balls, i.e. ($R/(R+B))$

You can use Hoeffding's inequality to show that:

$P[\mid \frac {X_R}{T}-p \mid \geq \epsilon] \leq 2e^{-2T\epsilon^{2}}$

Can you prove above?

Comment: In the equation you give, there is a recurring "e" value.  Is this the Euler constant in all 3 cases?  Or is it the "error" margin in one or more of the cases?

Comment: No. The $e$ is the Euler constant and $\epsilon$ is the error margin.

Comment: This is interesting, and might answer the question, but I would be surprised if this were the canonical answer for why statistics is valid, as it seems imprecise and non-algebraic.  For example, when I plug a sample size T = 400 and an error margin e = .05, I get that "the probability that the actual error is greater than or equal to tolerances is less than or equal to 0.27", which seems counterintuitive; I was expecting .05 (~95% confidence for a 5% error margin on 400 sample size).  Maybe "normal distribution" is a *hugely impactful* special case assumption in statistics?

Comment: I didn't get what you said about normal distribution. Anyway, can you explain why were you expecting $.05$?

Comment: Yes, going on my previous comment, if the sample size is 400, and the probability that our sample will be off by more than the 5% error margin is up to 27%, there's no way I would say "I'm 95% confident the error margin is less than 5%" (the canonical statistical result for the numbers given); in fact, I'm more likely to say "I'm 73% confident our error is less than 5%", not 95% confident, if I use the formula you give.